# Visual Basic OAuth2.0 Flow for connecting MS Access to Google Analytics API

Tags: ms-access, oauth-2.0, google-api, vba, google-oauth

I'm building a reporting dashboard in Microsoft Access, and one of the components of this dashboard requires pulling data from Google Analytics. I can get an Authentication Code easy enough from the Google API, but I'm running into issues exchanging the Auth Code for an Access Token and Refresh Token. I've tried lots of different things, but you can find my current code below.

```
Public Sub RefreshTokenFetch()

Dim xml As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

Dim url As String
url = "accounts.google.com/o/auth2/token?code=" & code & "&client_id=" & clientid & "&client_secret=" & secret & "&redirect_uri=" & redirect & "&grant_type=authorization_code"

Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")

With xml
    .Open "POST", url
    .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    .send
End With 

End Sub
```

When I try to run the above code, it will always gets tripped up on the ".send" line and says "this method cannot be called after the send method has been called."

I've tried finding some VB Oauth code, but I've had trouble finding the authentication token and refresh token state of the Oauth flow. All other questions and example code are for the actual Google API querying phase, once the tokens have been secured.

Answer (score 1):

Without specific knowledge of VB, there are a few general things you should correct:

1. urlencode each parameter
2. Since this is a POST (not a GET) remove query string "?code=...&..." from the URL and instead send the form data "code=...&..." in the body of the POST request.

See the following for details on this phase:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#handlingtheresponse

With respect to the VB part, I think that message may mean you need to specify the body as part of the .send, e.g.:.send "code=...&..."

The following site seems to have some examples (not specific to OAuth) that may be helpful:
http://www.tushar-mehta.com/publish_train/xl_vba_cases/vba_web_pages_services/#_Toc173749365