# Using Google OAuth2 in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, oauth2-playground

I'm trying to implement Google OAuth2 into an MSAccess database using POST? or GET?
I'm not very familiar with Google API.

1. What is the API Request URL?
2. What are the required headers?

I have attached an example that I'm currently using to send SMS using a POST with Twilio,
I'm guessing it's a similar concept using Google API which launches a browser? And shows the login screen which in return gives a response of the email? and if verified email = true?

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Public Const ACCOUNT_SID As String = "* REMOVED *"   ' << 'ACCOUNT_SID'
Public Const AUTH_TOKEN As String = "* REMOVED *"    ' << 'AUTH_TOKEN'
Public Const FROM_PHONE As String = "* REMOVED *"    ' << 'Twilio Number'
Private Const BASE_URL As String = "https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"

' Send Twilio SMS
Public Sub SendSMS(ByVal strTextFrom As String, ByVal strTextTo As String, ByVal strBody As String)
    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Dim objResponse         As Object
    Dim objRequest          As Object
    Dim strMessageURL       As String
    Dim strPostData         As String
    Dim strResponseStatus   As String
    
    ' Setup the request and authorization
    Set objRequest = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    
    ' Specify the URL
    strMessageURL = BASE_URL & ACCOUNT_SID & "/Messages.json"
    
    ' Open Request
    objRequest.Open "POST", strMessageURL, False, ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN

    ' Request Header
    objRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    
    ' Concatenate PostData
    strPostData = "From=" & URLEncode(strTextFrom) & "&To=" & URLEncode(strTextTo) & "&Body=" & strBody
    
    ' Send the PostData
    objRequest.Send strPostData
    
    ' Use JsonConverter to parse the reponse text
    Set objResponse = JsonConverter.ParseJson(objRequest.responseText)

    If objResponse("status") = "queued" Then
        strResponseStatus = Format$(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & " | " & "Status: Sent successfully"
        MsgBox strResponseStatus, vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Success"
    Else
        strResponseStatus = Format$(Now, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss") & " | " & "Status: " & objResponse("status") & " | " & "Message: " & objResponse("message") & " | " & "More Info: " & objResponse("more_info")
        MsgBox strResponseStatus, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Error"
    End If

Exit_Err_Handler:
    If Not objResponse Is Nothing Then Set objResponse = Nothing
    If Not objRequest Is Nothing Then Set objRequest = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & "Procedure: " & "SendSMS", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "SMS - Error"
    Resume Exit_Err_Handler
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Basic OAuth2.0 Flow for connecting MS Access to Google Analytics API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493486/visual-basic-oauth2-0-flow-for-connecting-ms-access-to-google-analytics-api)